# How to send parameter to a jsp page using querystring via a controller in spring framework?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP page containing a data Table. I want to pass the content of the first column of a row ,when clicked, to another jsp page. I am working with spring framework. I have tried to achieve it,but with some problem. The problem is : When I am retrieving the parameter in another jsp page, i get some content,but the contents after the first blank space are skipped.

Here is the code I have tried:
source jsp page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mytable tbody tr").click(function(){
    var aPos = $('#mytable').dataTable().fnGetPosition(this);
    var aData = $('#mytable').dataTable().fnGetData(aPos);     
    pass_on=aData[0];
    window.location.href = "/test/integrate"+"?"+"group="+pass_on;
});
});
```

the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/integrate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String pass_parameter_by_type(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

return "destination";
}
```

the destination jsp page:

```
<body>
<input type="button" id="sub_but">
<input type="hidden" value=<%=request.getParameter("group") %> id="group_parameter">
$("#sub_but").click(function(){
alert($("#group_parameter").val());             
        });
</body>
```

if the value passed is "cool guy", then in url it shows test/integrate?group=cool guy.
but in alert it shows only "cool".
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done to get the results:
I replaced blank with an underscore("_").

```
pass_on=aData[0];
var res=pass_on.replace(/ /g,"_");
window.location.href = "/test/integrate"+"?"+"group="+res;
```

No more changes. Rest of it works fine.
I still don't know why %20 didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass **cool%20guy**.

URLs don't understand special chars

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I replaced blank spaces with %20 but no change.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/integrate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String pass_parameter_by_type(ModelMap model,@RequestParam String group,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
model.addAttribute("group",group);
return "destination";
}
```

In your other JSP do like this:

```
<body>
<input type="button" id="sub_but">
<input type="hidden" value="${group}" id="group_parameter">
$("#sub_but").click(function(){
alert($("#group_parameter").val());             
        });
</body>
```

I hope it should solve your problem. :)

Comment: @ Shailesh Saxena: it throws error in controller:
 requestParam cannot be resolved to a type
 - The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type

Comment: Oops! My Mistake only! I edited my answer and kept the right code there.

Answer (score 0):

Encode your text. For javascript

```
escape(...)
```

For java, use:

```
URLEncoder.encode( ,encoding)
```